# Custom Module Menu Item Link Class Css

Tags: css, template-override, joomla-3.5, custom-module

I would like to customize a Menu module. I want to add a default CSS class to a Joomla 'my_template' to render all link menu items with a default class (`<a class="link_menu"...`).

I know that it is accomplished via menu item edit advanced tab options to adding a css class to a particular menu item. But i would like to add this class automatically to all the items of this menu module.

How could this be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would add module or menu class suffix to the menu module itself.

Then you can write the css specifically for that menu module type, applying the rules to every menu item in it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: Add a CSS class to your module in the **Advanced** Tab:

[image]

From here you can add for example a **Menu Class Suffix**, then via CSS you can add a rule to your menu items, for example if you add a class called **custom-menu**, the code will be:

```
.custom-menu li { /* your custom code */ }
```